# Android-Firebase realtime database stopped working after update

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase realtime database for past 6+ months. It worked well. But now I updated gradle dependencies to latest one and it stopped working. I didn't changed anything in code but it is neither reading nor writing.
My project level gradle google services version.

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
```

My app level firebase dependencies

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'
```

I didn't changed firebase database rules now.

```
{
 "rules": {
 ".read": true,
 ".write": true
  }
}
```

I tried to test the simple write code but it didn't updated in the firebase webview console.

```
FirebaseDatabase database4 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef4 = database4.getReference("BLB");
myRef4.setValue("Hello, World!");
```

Now if I add addValueEventListener to above myRef4 database object it will give "Hello World" in OnDataChanged method but no data in webview console. Is there any changes in implementation too along with new firebase SDK.
**Note :** I used Firebase client in android studio to integrate them.

Firebase logger in debug mode in Xiaomi mi note 4

```
06-24 11:41:18.311 9774-9943/com.package.subpackage D/WebSocket: ws_14 - WebSocket error.
bgg: error while creating secure socket to wss://d***-****.firebaseio.com/.ws?ns=***-1*****&v=5
    at bgd.d(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesc@12685025@12.6.85 (040408-197041431):104)
    at bge.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesc@12685025@12.6.85 (040408-197041431):4)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:760)
 Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:334)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:196)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:178)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:356)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:586)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.connect(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:265)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.connect(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:252)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:427)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:210)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket.<init>(SSLSocket.java:906)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.<init>(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:192)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(OpenSSLSocketFactoryImpl.java:68)
    at bgd.d(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesc@12685025@12.6.85 (040408-197041431):94)
    at bge.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesc@12685025@12.6.85 (040408-197041431):4) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:760)
```

**The same code working on other brand's devices.**

Comment: If the result of the write operation shows up locally but not on the database server, it sounds like your device can't connect to the server. I recommend [enabling debug logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase.html#setLogLevel(com.google.firebase.database.Logger.Level) and checking your logcat for a hint on the cause.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen logcat result attached. Please look into it and help me to solve this sir.

Comment: It looks like your Xiaomi mi note 4 device is not able to connect to the Firebase backend. I don't see from the error message why that is.

Comment: @blb007 I'm having the same issue. Did you resolve this?

Comment: @Astar Yes I resolved it. I just uninstalled app in phone(avd) and pulled code from remote git repository. I don't remember how it solved my problem but it did.

Answer (score 1):

For me it was a local lan network error.
*I needed to reboot the router.*

Trying to reboot the machine/phone and any network devices might help.